# Bootstrap, jQuery, and the Rails asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline, bootstrap-sass

This is my application.js manifest.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require_tree .
```

With this setup, sortable (JQuery), dropdowns (bootstrap) and modals (bootstrap) work in PRODUCTION on heroku.

In DEVELOPMENT, the dropdowns do NOT work.

When I place the bootstrap requires ABOVE jquery, ALL bootstrap and jquery stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the local drop down not working by using config.serve_static_assets = false in development.rb.

I am leaving the question in place to reference as an acceptable order for the 'requires' within the application.js manifest.