# Rails Asset Pipeline - CSS Not Updating

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to update the font in a rails app - specifically the text in a brand class in the top navbar.  I was successful in changing the font using google web fonts already, but now when I try to update the font again, it seems to be "stuck" on the last font I used.  I precompiled assets before deploying to heroku, which is what I think may be causing the problem.  Now the changes are not updating locally or in production.

I have done a few things to troubleshoot but none seem to be working:

1. Restarted the rails server
2. Emptied the cache folder in the tmp folder
3. Deleted public assets
4. Tried precompiling assets again - the font change does not work locally or on heroku
5. Tried targeting a more specific css selector (.navbar .brand versus .brand - it worked earlier for .brand so don't think that is the issue)
6. Cleared browsing history

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake - had a navbar class styled in my css with font-style: monospace.  After clearing that, everything worked - hopefully the troubleshooting steps help others!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using turbolinks? If so, read [this](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#asset-change-detection)

> **Asset change detection**
>
> You can track certain assets, like application.js and application.css,
>   that you want to ensure are always of the latest version inside a
>   Turbolinks session. This is done by marking those asset links with
>   data-turbolinks-track, like so:
>
> ```
> <link href="/assets/application-9bd64a86adb3cd9ab3b16e9dca67a33a.css"
> ```
>
> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-turbolinks-track>
>
> If those assets change URLs (embed an md5 stamp to ensure this), the
>   page will do a full reload instead of going through Turbolinks. This
>   ensures that all Turbolinks sessions will always be running off your
>   latest JavaScript and CSS.
>
> When this happens, you'll technically be requesting the same page
>   twice. Once through Turbolinks to detect that the assets changed, and
>   then again when we do a full redirect to that page.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using Turbolinks

Comment: I tried both of those - still not working but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. View your page source and search for the font src. If you can't find it skip to 3.
2. Test the font and display code outside of the rails apps to make sure it is the asset pipeline.
3. If the src and display code work, provide your application.css and application.js to check your manifests.
4. What config files/code have you changed since your last assets:precompile that is not working properly.

My similar issue: [Bootstrap, jQuery, and the Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243211/bootstrap-jquery-and-the-rails-asset-pipeline)